# Why does my tubeless tire keep sweating?

Tags: tire, tubeless, sealant

I have had this tires for almost a year.

They have been also been all this time like the photo, dropping some small drops:
[image: sweat]

One of them was profesonally installed in a shop ( so I expect is not an Installation issue).

The sealant is still working as I already had puncutures which got repaired on the spot and I only had to pump some air.

So apparently everything works fine, but it leaves those little drops all the time in the floor.

What is the reason of this? This also keeps dropping after 1 month of not touching the bike, but the tires don't loose pressure.

---

Further info:

Sealant is `Continental RevoSealant` and tyres are `Panaracer GravelKing SK TLC`.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/81167/tubeless-ready-tires-remain-porous-after-addition-of-sealant?noredirect=1&lq=1 (TL:DR: I was using a latex-free sealant, only certified for UST tires. Changing sealant (a more fluid one, with latex) solved the problem.

Comment: How often and how much you refill? How much escapes?

Comment: I use revosealant myself on 3 different MTB's and have never had this problem.  Are you running high tyre pressure?  and did you remember to give the bottle a really good shake before use?

Comment: @VladimirF I have not filled them again since I built them around a year ago.

I had two punctures that I could tell that got automatically repaired.

Comment: @AndyP I would say yes if the instructions told to do so. But I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: I am surprised that there is still anything in there. Doubly so with such leaks. I refill the sealant twice a year.

Answer (score 3):

I have found tremendous inconsistency in tubeless tires.  At first I believed excessive sealant "sweating" was due to my faulty installation and not adequately coating the inside of the tire with sealant.  After returning multiple tires of multiple brands for warranty replacements I can say with certainty that many tubeless tires are defective from the factory and weep / sweat sealant.  I use only Stan's standard sealant which is expected to be compatible with any tubeless tire.

A specific example:  I purchased 3 Panaracer Gravelking SK+ tires planning to install 2 and have 1 for future replacement as needed.  The 2 I initially installed continued to weep sealant for a week and over a hundred miles of riding.  The 3rd tire did not weep at all.  I returned the first 2 to Panaracer who replaced them under warranty.  The 2 replacements did not sweat.  So 2 out of 5 tires in my sample set were defective.  That's a 40% failure rate.

The 2 weeping tires came from a different vendor than the third good tire.  The fourth and fifth came direct from Panaracer.  Presumably the 5 tires came from 3 different manufacturing batches.  My conclusion is that there is wide variation in batches.

Similar results occurred with WTB and Kenda mountain and gravel tires.